Custom hex UUID template generator in Java
I have the following code (written by AI) that generates templates for uuids (It is template only, the prefix of 8 digits and postfix of 12 will be appended computed on different logic):
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

public class CustomUUIDGeneratorTemplate {
    private static final AtomicInteger COUNTER = new AtomicInteger(-1);

    public static String generateUUIDTemplate() {

        int count1 = COUNTER.incrementAndGet();

        String uuid = String.format("%04x-7%03x-%04x",
                count1 & 0xFFFFFFFFL,
                count1 & 0xFFFFFFFFL,
                count1 & 0xFFFFFFFFL
        );

        return uuid;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            System.out.println(generateUUIDTemplate());
        }
    }
}

It produces the following output:
0000-7000-0000
0001-7001-0001
0002-7002-0002

But I'm trying to achieve a different output:
0000-7000-0001
0000-7000-0002
0000-7000-0003

When the last digits are near the end, the digits on the left should increment and look like this:
0000-7fff-ffff
0001-7000-ffff

How to achieve this? Any help would be appreciated.

this is not a correct UUID

It is template only, the prefix of 8 digits and postfix of 12 will be appended computed on different logic

All use of generative AI (e.g., ChatGPT1 and other LLMs) is banned when posting content on Stack Overflow.
This includes "asking" the question to an AI generator then copy-pasting its output as well as using an AI generator to "reword" your answers.
Please see the Help Center article: What is this site’s policy on content generated by generative artificial intelligence tools?

I’m voting to close this question because it uses code copy pasted from AI.

First of all, why do you want to create a custom template? The format for a UUID is very tightly defined (see here).
But if you insist, I'd use java.util.UUID and chop off the beginning and end because you are looking for a valid subset of a UUID.
public static String dumbUUID() {
    return UUID.randomUUID().toString().substring(4, 18);
}

